# Google Business Messages API has not been used in project before or it is disabled issue

Tags: google-api, google-business

I am getting below error while sending a Google Business Messages via API

> *Business Messages API  has not been used in project 7170339412 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/businessmessages.googleapis.com/overview?project=7170339412 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry*

But under API Library, I am not able to find Business Messages API so that I can enable it. Is it referred with any other name?

Below screenshots of what I see:

[image: API_Librarry_Screenshot1]

[image: API_Library_Screenshot2]

[image: API_Library_Screenshot3]

Answer (score 1):

The [Business Messages api](https://developers.google.com/business-communications/business-messages/guides/quickstarts/prerequisite-setup) is a restricted API you need apply for permission to access it.

Due to the fact that its a restricted api that name is not going to appear under libary.

The page linked there describes how to apply

[image]

Comment: I've done that, but in my Projects API Library still missing Business Messages API.

Comment: Contagt google if they gave you access to a restricted api you have contat